# "class, interface, or enum expected" error when trying to create package

Tags: java, package

I'm trying to declare a package in a file as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

package rtg;

public class Generate
{
    // ...
}
```

But I'm getting an error when I try to compile this:

```
Generate.java:3: class, interface, or enum expected package rtg;
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it should be

```
package rtg;
import java.util.*;
public class Generate{
}
```

In java you first define package then imports and then class. See wiki here: [Java_package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package) and Oracle's tutorial here: [Java Packages](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)

---

**Edit**

Now to call Genereate class from a class in same folder that is rtg folder:

```
package rtg;
public class GUI{
     Generate gen = new Generate();
}
```

Make sure all words are spelled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The pacakge declaration must be the first thing in a Java file (apart from comments). You can't put the imports above it.

Answer (score 0):

All the examples are above is good but we have to compile this package making  class by swich standard ... You have to give "-d" and destinations folder for making package in it. "c: \f1 >javac -d e: \f2 temp . Java"     'c,e'are drive, 'f1,f2' are folder, temp is class name.